# docker run phpmyadmin inside alpine container

Tags: mysql, tomcat, docker, phpmyadmin, alpine-linux

I discovered docker last week and am playing around withit for a decent time.
Now I want to deploy a Website inside a Container. The Website is already finished and I got all the files on my host system. It needs php, java, tomcat and - and here is the problem - a mysql-db.

So I created a Dockerfile, using alpine:latest as base image and after that installing the above named applications one by one.

```
FROM alpine:latest

ENV http_proxy http://not_important/
RUN apk update
RUN apk --no-cache --quiet add openjdk8
RUN apk --no-cache --quiet add nano
RUN apk --no-cache --quiet add php7
RUN apk --no-cache --quiet add mysql
RUN apk --no-cache --quiet add phpmyadmin

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/tomcat/
COPY apache-tomcat-9.0.4.tar.gz /usr/local/tomcat/

RUN cd /usr/local/tomcat/ && tar xzf /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.4.tar.gz
RUN mv /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/* /usr/local/tomcat
RUN rm -r /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.4
RUN rm -r /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.4.tar.gz

CMD ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
```

But now, I dont rly know how to finish my work. How am I able to start the mysql-db and access it with phpmyadmin?

I run the container with the following command:

```
docker run --name alpine_custom -dit -p 30000:8080 -p31000:80 alpine:custom
```

The tomcat is running on port 30000 without a problem and I want phpmyadmin to be accessable over port 31000. I do have a working MySQL-DB on my Host and manage it with phpmyadmin (meaning, there are two containers, the phpmyadmin container is linked with the database)...

Is it even possible to do it like I want it, or do I have to deploy a second container with a database which is linked with my alpine container (and a third one with phpmyadmin...)?

I am thankful for every answer, thank you in advance

Sincerely
Telvanis :)

PS: I know, the Dockerfile isn't very good but i think its enough for my needs ^^

Answer (score 3):

#### Try to avoid having it *"all-in-one"*.

This is the idea behind Docker, to go from something *"monolithic"* to something which is separated to components. This approach gives you an advantage when you want to scale up/down your app, update specific components without rebuilding the whole app... etc.

#### Try to avoid the installation & configuration of every technology on your own

I remember myself trying to do so with MySQL. I spent much time and had no result. Ended up using the official image. The installation of a software inside docker might have tricky parts and not be the same with the installation one does in a VM.
So, I would propose to start searching for the official images of the technologies that you are trying to put into use. Docker hub has plenty and most of them also **provide guidelines** on how to use/configure them. For example:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/
- https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/
- https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/

...you get the idea.

Your running `containers` will have `names`. Docker offers a DNS mechanism so that your containers can connect to each other by using these names. For example if you have a container for your MySQL database named `my_app_db` listening on port `5000`, configure the phpmyadmin container to connect there. **An important notice here:** don't try these on the default network, because it will not work. Define your own test-network.

Dealing with 3,4,5... or maybe more containers will make you type commands to `build` them, `run` them, `start`/`stop` them. Here is where `docker-compose` comes in and proves to be very handy. Within a `docker-compose.yml` file, you can define a "composition" of inter-connecting containers and handle them with single commands like `docker-compose up`, `docker-compose down` etc...

#### Working example:

comes from [here](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker/blob/master/docker-compose.testing.yml), but is slightly modified...

`docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'

services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: phpmyadmin_testing_mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test123

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: phpmyadmin_testing
    volumes:
      - /sessions
    ports:
      - 8090:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - TESTSUITE_PASSWORD=test123
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

To run, simply use `docker-compose up`. To connect, use:

- server: `phpmyadmin_testing_mysql` (the name of the MySQL container)
- username: `root`
- password: `test123`

[image]

Comment: Wow :o Thank you for your work, I'll try it :) Thank you for your time!